# Virtual host will NOT work in MAMP but works on localhost:8888

Tags: apache, mamp, httpd.conf, virtual-hosts

Created a new Laravel project in `htdocs` in MAMP. Followed all the steps, added virtual hosts, changed conf file, etc/hosts, restarted mamp and my pc several times but I just can't get my virtual host to run.

however, when I am in the `MAMP Dashboard` I can navigate to `my website -> website -> public` and the default Laravel boilerplate page appears.

Has anyone had this issues with MAMP before? I gave up with XAMPP and Valet so it's my last chance here..

**Specs**
High Sierra 10.13.5 on 2015 MBP,
Composer version 1.6.5,
php 7.2.7

**httpd.conf**

```
# Virtual hosts
Include /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

**httpd-vhosts**

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /Applications/MAMP/htdocs
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "Applications/MAMP/htdocs/website/public"
    ServerName website.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

**etc/hosts**

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
#255.255.255.255        broadcasthost
#::1             localhost

127.0.0.1 website.dev
```

Comment: *but I just can't get my virtual host to run* as in? it did not show the website? is this path correct `DocumentRoot "Applications/MAMP/htdocs/website/public"` ?

Comment: `This site can't be reached` is what is returned in the browser when I hit `website.dev `. I believe the path is correct unless I need a `/` or `~/` before it, but I did not see that in any examples..

Comment: using `/` means the path is started from the root, while without one means it is located relative to the `httpd` executable i believe.. can you try to use full path first?

Answer (score 1):

`website.dev` is technically a public url, so the browser is looking for it on the internet I guess. I was trapped once in this dreadful situation. changing the name to something like `website.local` should solve your issue. It did for me.